# Using notepad++ to swap case of certain characters

Tags: notepad++, case-sensitive

I have a long text file and trying to make some edits.

Is there a way in Notepad++ to swap the case of specific characters?

My list looks like this

```
John:Abcd
Henry:abcd
Samantha:Abcd
```

I want to swap the case of the letter after : so the output would be like this

```
John:abcd
Henry:Abcd
Samantha:abcd
```

Is this possible on Notepad++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=:)(?:([A-Z])|([a-z]))`
- Replace with: `\L$1\U$2`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=:)          # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a colon before
(?:             # non capture group
    ([A-Z])       # group 1, an uppercase letter
  |             # OR
    ([a-z])       # group 2, a lowercase letter
)               # end group
```

**Replacement:**

```
\L$1        # convert group 1 to lowercase
\U$2        # convert group 2 to uppercase
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]